# Mac Keybindings with German umlauts

Tags: vba, macos, ms-word

I know how to bind a key to a sub in VBA for Mac (Word 2016 etc.). But I can't find a way to do so with German umlauts. I already created some code to bind all 255 variations of wdKey to code, but that didn't get me a solution either. The keys ä, ö, ü on my keyboard never fire any event.

I'd be happy for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is possible.

Some notes:

It looks as if you asked a similar question [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/assign-macro-to-special-keys-like-umlaut-or/c7e12dd3-6cc4-4540-ab69-c074e5dacd6e?auth=1) in 2012, and the suggestion in there that the problem is that these keys cannot be assigned in Word, only in Mac OS, seems still to be correct. However, that seems to mean that you can only assign a key combination that Mac OS allows you to assign, to an existing Word menu item. So you *can* use that mechanism to assign `ctrl-ö` to "Advanced Symbol..." but you *cannot* use that mechanism to assign `ctrl-ö` to a Word internal command name and I do not think you can assign `ö`, on its own, to anything.

In Windows Word, I was able to assign `alt-ö`, `alt-ä` and `alt-ü` to "InsertSymbol" in Word, but the keystrokes Word *actually* assigned this comand to were the Alt-shifted wdKeyBackSingleQuote, wdKeySingleQuote, and wdKeySemiColon.

Attempting to use the same key assignments in Mac VBA did not work.

On my (UK) keyboard, the actual keys used for `ö`, `ä` and `ü` are SemiColon, Comma, and LeftSquareBracket. Even on the US English keyboard, I think they are SemiColon, SingleQuote, and LeftSquareBracket, so it is not obvious why Word assigns those particular codes. I think you would probably have to understand how DOS and Widnows *and* Word deal with keyboard scan codes to make sense of it, and on Mac it will of course be different.

For anyone wishing to explore further, you can use VBA to reassign a key without using BuildKeyCode, like this:

```
Dim i As Integer
i = 1022
KeyBindings.Add KeyCode:=i, _
  KeyCategory:=wdKeyCategoryCommand, _
  Command:="InsertSymbol"
```

Some values of i cause an "Invalid Parameter" command, and others a 5346 "Word cannot change the function of the specified key". Most of these values of i probably just represent a "base keystroke" such as "A", eithe ron its own or combined with one or more shifts such as Shift, Alt, etc., but without exploring every single possibile value of i that does not raise an error it is difficult to be certain that there are no other possibilities.